# how do you get current request's in aiohttp when it isn't a handler

Tags: request, python-3.6, aiohttp

I have an aiohttp app that has some endpoints created using nested apps.

My use case is once the request is processed, I want to return not in web.response format but whatever format is requested by the client in their request's header (could be csv, json, html etc).

So I was using a decorator and from that decorator wrapper, getting the current request to know the header `format` and process the response to that type.

My question is how can I get current request's context. I know there isn't anything like `current_app` like in flask, so what's the best of doing what I want to do.

Below I am posting some code that explains above content:

```
@subapp_routes.get('')
@subapp_routes.get('/{c_id}')
@format_output
async def index(request):
    print(request)
    c_id = request.match_info.get('c_id', None)
    return await get_index(c_id) 

def format_data_object(data):
    status = 200

    mime = _most_acceptable_format(request, data) # HOW TO PASS THIS CURRENT request AS CURRENTLY THIS ISN'T GETTING RECOGNIZED. I TRIED aiohttp.request and aiohttp.web.request but get not recognized, so not sure now

    if mime == MIME_DATAFRAME:
        return _render_dataframe(data, status)
    elif mime == MIME_CSV:
        return _render_csv(data, status)
    elif mime == MIME_JSON:
        return _render_json(data, status)
    elif mime == MIME_HTML:
        return _render_html(data, status)
    raise InvalidRequest('unrecognized format: "%s"' % mime)


def format_output(function):
    """
    Output format decorator.
    """
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            data = function(*args, **kwargs)

            return format_data_object(data)
        except Exception as ex:
            return handle_error(ex)
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flask` way spoils people.

If you need an entire request, DB connection or other resource -- explicitly pass it into called function.

Very obvious and elegant way which doesn't require any implicit context namespace magic.

Please left things like threadlocal variables to system tools, user code should not use them for sake of simplicity and readability.